# Nifi: Get values form a Json by a Jsonpath, those were defined in other Json

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jsonpath

I have two Json:

Json1:

```
{
    "level_1": [
      {
        "level_2_1": [
          {
             
            "key_2_1": "value_1",
            "key_2_2": "value_2",
            
          },
          {
            "key_2_1": "value_1",
            "key_2_3": "value_3",
          },
          {
            "key_2_1": "value_1",
            "key_2_4": "value_4",
          }   
        ],
        "level_2_2": {
          "key_2_2_1": "2022-08-30T06:57:31.331Z",
          "key_2_2_2": "2022"
        } 
      }
    ]
}
```

Json2

```
{
  "level_1" : {
    "level_2_1" : {
      "value" : "default value",
      "type" : "String"
    },
    "level_2_2" : {
      "value" : "level_1[0].level_2_1[0].key_2_2", // this Jsonpath of Json 1
      "type" : "String"
    },
    "level_2_3" : {
      "value" : "level_1[0].level_2_2.key_2_2_1", // this Jsonpath of Json 1
      "type" : "String"
    }
}
```

I want to get the result like this (these Values come from json1)

```
{
  "level_1" : {
    "level_2_1" : {
      "value" : "default value",
      "type" : "String"
    },
    "level_2_2" : {
      "value" : "value_1", // this Value of Json 1
      "type" : "String"
    },
    "level_2_3" : {
      "value" : "2022-08-30T06:57:31.331Z", // this Value of Json 1
      "type" : "String"
    }
}
```

please, can you give me some advice. Thank for your help!!

Comment: not clear where do you have those 2 jsons.

Comment: i got them from other processors

Comment: Please be spesific in order the others to be able to reproduce the case by sharing the related processors.